# Widget control - putting a slideshow in the widget area

Tags: widgets

I am trying to put a slideshow in the widget area of my wordress theme... do you know of anyway to do this instead of html in the widget area?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Two basic approaches would be:

1. Modify template file and insert/call code near where sidebar is called.
2. Create custom widget with your code or call to it and place it in sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

*Use the technique I posted here:*
 **[How to process content in a widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31437/how-to-process-content-in-a-widget/)** 
and do whatever you want with the string values in Widget properties before display.

*You can even enable shortcodes in Widgets.*