# How to process content in a widget?

Tags: widgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is There A Hook To Process The Content Of The Text Widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/is-there-a-hook-to-process-the-content-of-the-text-widget)

I have created a plugin that uses tokens in the body content to dynamically insert certain content.  For example:

%%keyword%%

At page request, that would get replaced with a keyword specified in the incoming URL.

I would like to be able to use these tokens in a widget and have them processed the same, but my plugin only knows about `the_content` and I haven't been able to figure out, how to tell it to parse the content of widgets as well, before final page render.

How would this be done?  I suppose it can be done more easily with shortcodes, but I'd like to stay consistent with my token usage.

Appreciate any suggestions!

EDIT:

Minutes after posting I found this post which has given me what I need:

[Is There A Hook To Process The Content Of The Text Widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/is-there-a-hook-to-process-the-content-of-the-text-widget)

Thanks anyway all!

Answer (score 1):

The filter you're looking for is `widget_text`.  From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Widgets):

> **widget_text**
>   applied to the widget text of the WordPress Text widget. May also apply to some third party widgets as well.

Comment: yep just found this post:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/is-there-a-hook-to-process-the-content-of-the-text-widget thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code will allow you to make replacements in all Widgets, on all strings present in their $instance arrays.

```
// Hook into 'widget_display_callback' filter
// It allows altering a Widget properties right before it outputs in sidebar
add_filter('widget_display_callback', function($instance, $widget, $args){
    // Recursive functions that applies replacements in all string elements of $instance
    $fnFixArray = function($v) use (&$fnFixArray){
        // Dig deeper if this is an array or object
        if(is_array($v) or is_object($v)){
            // Use pointer here for property to satisfy both array/object in one
            // Otherwise for arrays we need $v[$k1] and $v->{$k1} for objects
            foreach($v as $k1=>&$v1){
                // Go recursive on elements / properties
                $v1 = $fnFixArray(v1);
            }
            return $v;
        }
        // Don't alter non-strings or empty ones
        if(!is_string($v) or empty($v)) return $v;
        // We found a string, replace stuff in it and return the altered value
        return str_replace('%REPLACEWHAT%', '%REPLACEWITH%', $v);
    };
    return $fnFixArray($instance);
}, 11, 3); // We need 3 arguments and a below normal priority
```

***It's a bit more advanced but it's WHAT you really need.***

And the same thing with **array_walk_recursive()** which recurses objects also:

```
// Hook into the 'widget_display_callback' filter
// It allows altering a Widget properties right before output in sidebar
add_filter('widget_display_callback', function($instance, $widget, $args){
    // This digs through arrays and objects all the way to non-iterative level
    array_walk_recursive($instance, function(&$value, $key){
        // Don't alter non-strings or empty ones
        if(!is_string($value) or empty($value)) return;
        // We found a string, replace stuff in it and return the altered value
        $value = str_replace('%REPLACEWHAT%', '%REPLACEWITH%', $value);
    });
    // Return the possible altered $instance array
    return $instance;
}, 11, 3);
```

*Have fun!*